# Conserve the frame in a mdframed box that spans more than one page

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

I am using `mdframed` to create big boxes that span more than one page, but they just leave an unframed side at the top and down of the page. Is there a way to solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% demo option just for the example
\usepackage{blindtext}% demo option just for the example
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[xcolor,framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\global\mdfdefinestyle{tag}{%
    roundcorner=5pt,innerlinewidth=2pt,innerlinecolor=RubineRed,%
    middlelinewidth=3pt,middlelinecolor=white,%
    outerlinewidth=2pt,outerlinecolor=Melon,%
    backgroundcolor=Melon!20,%
}
\begin{mdframed}[style=tag]     
\begin{center}
    \blindtext
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo}
         \captionof{figure}{This is foo.}
        \label{fig:foo}
    \blindtext
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo}
         \captionof{figure}{This is foo2.}
        \label{fig:foo}
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
\end{center}
Lots of text
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo}
         \captionof{figure}{This is foo3.}
        \label{fig:foo}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: *Do* post an image and remove the preceding `!`. Those with editing privileges will re-insert it to embed the image in your post.

Comment: So you want the frame to be closed on top and bottom whenever there is a page break? I think that that is a feature so that it is clear that this frame continues on to the next page, or is being continued from the previous page.

Comment: Use the option `everyline=true`. The global is useless. It is only needed in my example files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to answer this question with some hints to your preamble.

- The command `\global` in front of `\mdfdefinestyle` isn't needed. I used it in the documentation do define the style out of the group provided by `showexpl`
- You load the package `xcolor`. As recommend it's the best way to do this. If the package `xcolor` is loaded `mdframed` will ignore the option `xcolor`.
- To draw also a top and bottom line at splitted frames you can use the option `everyline=true`. However in my opinion it doesn't look well with such borders.

Use the following definition for `tag`:

```
\mdfdefinestyle{tag}{%
    roundcorner=5pt,innerlinewidth=2pt,innerlinecolor=RubineRed,%
    middlelinewidth=3pt,middlelinecolor=white,%
    outerlinewidth=2pt,outerlinecolor=Melon,%
    backgroundcolor=Melon!20,everyline=true%
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I replace above code but still same pblm. i am getting following error message. ! Package keyval Error: everyline undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.