# How to control mdframed on multiple pages?

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed, wrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conserve the frame in a mdframed box that spans more than one page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57135/conserve-the-frame-in-a-mdframed-box-that-spans-more-than-one-page)

I am using mdframed for writing citation information but citation list is too long which comes in 2-3 pages.Mdframed automatically spreads on multiple pages but with open box. How can i close box on each page dynamically.

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: I am getting  ! Package keyval Error: everyline undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
After using given solution.

Comment: @manish You probably have an outdated version of `mdframed`.

Comment: How can i update mdframed? I am using TexLive 2011.

Comment: I have installed latest version. Now it is working fine.

Comment: I just found it works but there is now new line at the begining or closing of box. It looks very odd when text begins after box without any spacing. How can i add one newline.